# SpringBoot 2.5.3 does not work on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to upgrade SpringBoot from v2.4.0 to 2.5.3.
My Boot project installs and runs fine locally with both versions.

Version 2.4.0 works fine on Beanstalk. When updating to 2.5.3 however, nginx returns a 301 for all requests to the Boot application. I am testing on the same instance (so same config) on Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.7.

The SpringBoot logs are identical between the 2 when starting up on both local and SpringBoot minus a few verbiage changes. No other changes exist in the code.

I'm a bit stuck. I've reviewed the Java logs, nginx, Beanstalk init logs, and everything looks fine.

**Edit** I am looking for suggestions on troubleshooting next steps for AWS Beanstalk SpringBoot apps as the 2 version produce identical EB and app logs, and I am not sure where else I should be looking.

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?